# Найти MAC в бинарном файле

Tags: binary, mac-address

Прошил IP-Телефон прошивкой напрямую программатором. У телефона есть сетевая карта ну и соответственно MAC адрес. Так вот, после прошивки он сменился. Не могу найти где он записан в прошивке - чтобы вернуть обратно заводской. (Несколько устройств не могут работать в одной Ethernet сети с одинаковым MAC адресом)

MAC: 00:15:65:8D:35:50

Ссылка на файл: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/702487352534106112/907502508946120714/25q64

Comment: Hex-редактор в помощь, просто вводите известный MAC в поиск, находите искомое смещение и задаёте нужное значение

Comment: Хотя, может всё и не так просто. Указанный MAC точно есть в прошивке, или это исходный? Прямой подстановкой не находится

Comment: @SunnyCove - попробуйте байты попарно местами попереставлять, и искать не весь MAC, а хотя бы пару байт из него - например, 35 50 или 50 35

Comment: @gbg, уже, и пока безуспешно. Вернее, пару байт найти можно, только вот их соседи не похожи на фрагменты мака

Comment: Тогда, вероятно, прошивка пожата или зашифрована (или все вместе), и история становится интереснее.